# Series of httpRequests in Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform

I want to do a series of httpRequests in Cloud Code. [Promises](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Promise.html) [seemed](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises-series) to be good for this.
I have the URLs in an array like so:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("serialRequests", function(request, response) {
  var urls = ["http://www.htmldog.com/examples/headings1.html", "http://www.htmldog.com/examples/headings2.html", "http://www.htmldog.com/examples/lists1.html", "http://www.htmldog.com/examples/lists2.html"];
  var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
  var count = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    var url = urls[i];
    promise = promise.always(function() {
      return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: url,
        success: function(httpResponse) {
          console.log("Response: " + httpResponse.text);
          count++;
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
          console.log("Status: " + httpResponse.status);
          count++;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  promise.always(function() {
    console.log("Count: " + count);
    return response.success();
  });
});
```

Despite `count` being 4 after running the code, the response is **not** always of the URL the request was made with:

```
I2014-07-19T06:11:41.807Z]Response: Response of the first URL in the array
I2014-07-19T06:11:42.084Z]Response: Response of the last URL in the array
I2014-07-19T06:11:42.356Z]Response: Response of the last URL in the array
I2014-07-19T06:11:42.624Z]Response: Response of the last URL in the array
I2014-07-19T06:11:42.640Z]Count: 4
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there an alternative to my solution?

Comment: Take a look at the Promises in Series example again. It does not use `always`. Also, can you include the full log of what is printed when this is run?

Comment: @HectorRamos I have added the full log to the question. `always` is used instead of `then` to not break the chain if one request fails. If `then` is used and all requests succeed, the log is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty late to the party, but my guess is that you're overriding promise the way you're calling things, rather than just extending the chain.

Do these need to be run one after another? If not, you should create a new Parse.Promise() for each iteration, and add it to an array. Then, after the for loop, return Parse.Promise.when( arrayOfPromsies ).then() , with the then() containing your last promise call there that returns the count and all that.  This requires the order in which your httpRequests get called not actually mattering, just that they all happen, regardless of how many fail, which looks to me what you might want.

If they do need to be run one after another, you'll have to change your implementation to use a helper function, in which you pass the count of your array, the current index, and a reference to your array, and return a call to the function itself, incrementing the index, with a .then() returning a promise from the function.